# Update UI from running thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to write a download manager app, in the `activity` I add a progress bar which show the current progress to the user, now if user touch the back button and re-open the `activity` again this `ProgressBar` won't be updated.

To avoid from this problem I create a single thread with unique name for each download that keep progress runnable and check if that thread is running in `onResume` function, if it is then clone it to the current thread and re-run the new thread again but it won't update my UI either, Any ideas !?

```
@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
    for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++)
        if (threadArray[i].getName().equals(APPLICATION_ID))
        {
            mBackground = new Thread(threadArray[i]);
            mBackground.start();
            downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(showcaseActivity.this
                    , "Find that thread - okay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}

private void updateProgressBar()
{
    Runnable runnable = new updateProgress();
    mBackground  = new Thread(runnable);
    mBackground.setName(APPLICATION_ID);
    mBackground.start();
}

private class updateProgress implements Runnable
{
    public void run() 
    {
        while (Thread.currentThread() == mBackground)
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                Message setMessage = new Message();
                setMessage.what = mDownloadReceiver.getProgressPercentage();        
                mHandler.sendMessage(setMessage);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {/* Do Nothing */}
    }
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message getMessage) 
    {
        downloadProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        downloadProgressBar.setProgress(getMessage.what);
        if (getMessage.what == 100)
            downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

Download button code:

```
downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        downloadProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        downloadProgressBar.setMax(100);    
        Intent intent = new Intent(showcaseActivity.this, downloadManagers.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://test.com/t.zip");
        intent.putExtra("receiver", mDownloadReceiver);
        startService(intent);
        updateProgressBar();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend reading the Android Developer blog post on [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html). As it states, the easiest way to update your UI from another thread is using [Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: +1 `runOnUiThread` is the bestest (?) way. Fast and readable. When will they release an official toolkit that abstracts this kind of crap away, I wonder...

Comment: @ianhanniballake But I update my thread in my activity without any problem, once I go back or pause the activity and then re-open it I lost the UI

Comment: @iSun - if you are doing background activities that need to outlast your activity, then you should not be using Threads at all, but instead a Service that sends broadcasts to any listening Activities (which then receive and update the UI). You may want to consider using LocalBroadcastManager to send broadcasts only within your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting `LocalBroadcastManager`.